# how to write active record query for selecting certain values in a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dogs table which has age as an attribute. Dogs with ages between 1 year -12 years are in one column and dogs under 1 year have different column. I want to be abel to select dogs that are between 8 - 12 years in age and count them. This is my query but it only selects one dog with certain age.

```
@checkup = Dog.where(age: 8).count
```

Comment: Try `@checkup = Dog.where(age: 8..12).count`

Comment: Yes! Thank. it works. What if I had to select multiple string values in a column?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking,try asking another question explaining what you need. Meanwhile please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the below should work

```
@checkup = Dog.where(age: 8..12).count
```

which returns the count of the dogs which are between 8-12.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Pavan you could use a range to create a `BETWEEN` query.

```
@checkup = Dog.where(age: 8..12).count
```

But this approach is still flawed since you have to periodically update all your records as time passes!

Instead use a `Date` column to record the birthdate of the dogs.

```
rails g migration AddBirthdateToDogs birthdate:date
rake db:migrate
```

Then you can select the dogs by:

```
Dog.where(birthdate: 8.years.ago..12.years.ago
```

Or if you want to be fancy you can create a class method:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Select dogs by age
  # @param [Range, Fixnum] age
  # @return [ActiveRecord::Relation]
  # @example
  #   Dog.aged(0)
  #   Dog.aged(1..2) 
  def self.aged(age)
    if age.respond_to?(:map)
      age = age.map do |x|
        x.is_a?(Date)? x : x.years.ago  
      end 
      age = age.first..(age.last + 1.year)
    elsif age.respond_to?(:year)
      age = age.year.ago..(age + 1.year)
    end
    self.where(birthdate: ago)
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also use a DateTime but I doubt you need that level of precision.

Comment: I am going over the fancy method you gave and I am learning more. Thanks.